# SQL Server Management Studio Unable to Start Correctly

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssms

I recently installed SQL Server Management Studio 18.5. I get an application error when I try to launch...

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."
```

I have downloaded the latest .Net Framework, Visual C++ Redistributable. I have also repaired, reinstalled severally and ran as administrator most of the time.
I checked the ssms.exe.config in the installation folder. VS says the `logpath` and `encrypt` attributes are not allowed.

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="UserSettings" switchName="SourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="logFile" type="Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.LogFileTraceListener,&#xD;&#xA;                        Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
                        logPath="%TEMP%\SSMS\" encrypt="false" >
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
...
```

This is the error I pulled from the post install log...

```
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6E97ABB5-75F1-4C05-A317-F0A23840262B}v15.0.18330.0\x64\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {6E97ABB5-75F1-4C05-A317-F0A23840262B}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Note: 1: 1707 
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1707 
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:580]: Product: SSMS Post Install Tasks -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (s) (98:C8) [17:32:40:582]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SSMS Post Install Tasks. Product Version: 15.0.18330.0. Product Language: 1033.
```

Comment: Are they allowing `&#xD;&#xA;` in class attributes now?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning They were passed as characters in line 5. No errors.

Comment: I'm sure they're perfectly valid XML but that doesn't make them valid characters in `assembly` and `type` attributes which are expecting to follow a particular format. Also you should be using add in the self-closing style, `<add ... />`